# JPA Select Query with composite primary key leads an exception

Tags: java, jpa

I have tried the below code for getting the single NotificationSubType Object. But finding exception like " **org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Encountered "from" at character 1, but expected: ["DELETE", "SELECT", "UPDATE"].**"

Please help me on given problem.
Code is given below : 
...
...

```
try {

    Query query = this.em.createQuery("from NotificationSubType conc WHERE conc.id.alertTyC = ?1 and conc.id.alertSubTyC = ?2");

    query.setParameter(1, "MPPRINT");
    query.setParameter(2, "REIN");

    NotificationSubType trackIdResLst = (NotificationSubType)query.getSingleResult();

    if (null != trackIdResLst) {
        System.out.println("TRUE");
    } else{
        System.out.println("FALSE");
    }   
} catch (Exception e) {
    NotificationLogger.errorWithThrowable(e);
    throw new NotificationServiceException(e.getMessage());
}
```

...

Answer (score 1):

Why not read the exception? and read the `JPA` spec ?

`JPQL` statements have to start with `SELECT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE`. Anything other than those is illegal (and yours starts with `FROM` for some reason). Put a `SELECT` and the candidate alias in front of it for more chance of success

Yes `Hibernate` bastardises the `JPQL` standard with `HQL` (which allows you to omit SELECT plus the alias) but you are using `OpenJPA` so you need to use `JPA` compliant queries, and besides it would be good practice even when using Hibernate to obey the standard!

Comment: Thanks for your great input. I also tried with select . It's giving success for plain select query like "select * from NotificationSubType", but when I am adding condition like "select * from NotificationSubType conc WHERE conc.id.alertTyC = ?1 and conc.id.alertSubTyC = ?2"  Its giving error. Is there anything I need to configure for conditional select query in Open JPA?

Comment: As I said ... read the JPA spec. You cannot do "SELECT *" in JPQL! "SELECT conc FROM  NotificationSubType conc" is JPQL!. Please read documentation rather than randomly throwing SQL at JPA. JPQL != SQL